# Retrieving the nth term of an infinite stream

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, comparative-review, generator

I recently learned how generators can be infinite in Python. For example, the infinite sequence can be the triangular numbers: 
$$1, 3, 6, 10,...$$

```
def triangle_stream():
    """ Infinite stream of triangle numbers. """
    x = step = 1
    yield x
    while True:
        step += 1
        x += step
        yield x
```

I wrote a function that returns the *n*<sup>th</sup> term in an infinite sequence.

```
def nth_term(generator, n):
    """ Returns the nth term of an infinite generator. """
    for i, x in enumerate(generator()):
        if i == n - 1:
            return x
```

As an example:

```
>>> nth_term(triangle_stream, 10)
55
```

But this `nth_term` function also works:

```
def nth_term(generator, n):
    """ Returns the nth term of an infinite generator. """
    x = generator()
    for i in range(n - 1):
        next(x)
    return next(x)
```

Which of these two `nth_term` functions is more efficient?

Comment: Have you done performance testing? I would guess that the second will be faster because you remove an if statement, but the best way to find out would be to test.

Comment: I'm using repl.it, I'm not sure if performance testing is possible on that

Comment: what about timeit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two modifications that I would make right away would be:

1. to use iterables instead of a generator function as parameter to allow for more genericity: this way I could use `nth_term` using either `triangle_stream()` or `itertools.cycle('ABCD')` as parameters;
2. to index elements in base 0 instead of base 1, so `nth_term(triangle_stream(), 0)` would return 1 instead of looping indefinitely and `nth_term(triangle_stream(), 1)` would return 3 instead of 1.

Now, making the function accept any iterable, I would use something along the lines of the second version this will be closer to my final proposition that will `raise StopIteration` if there is not enough elements instead of silently returning `None` ("Errors should never pass silently."). But applying both suggestions would lead to:

```
def nth_term(iterable, n):
    """Returns the nth term of any iterable."""
    for i, x in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == n:
            return x
```

or

```
def nth_term(iterable, n):
    """Returns the nth term of any iterable."""
    x = iter(iterable)
    for i in range(n):
        next(x)
    return next(x)
```

Now, instead of manually calling `next` on the iterator in the second version, I would ask `zip` to do it for me. Chances are that the execution will spend less time in the Python interpreter and more in the C part of `zip` and so be faster:

```
def nth_term(iterable, n):
    """Returns the nth term of any iterable."""
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for _ in zip(range(n), iterator):
        pass
    return next(iterator)
```

Lastly, I would use existing tools to perform the iteration for me: [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is exactly what we need. In fact, your very function is already listed in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

I would however remove the default value, especially in the case of an infinite iterable:

```
def nth(iterable, n):
    "Returns the nth item or raise StopIteration"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None))
```

---

A completely unrelated note, but I would move the `yield x` at the beginning of the loop in `triangle_stream` so that you don't have to write it twice:

```
def triangle_stream():
    """ Infinite stream of triangle numbers. """
    x = step = 1
    while True:
        yield x
        step += 1
        x += step
```

And since `step` starts at 1, and never stop incrementing one by one, I would use [`itertools.count(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
def triangle_stream():
    """ Infinite stream of triangle numbers. """
    x = 0
    for step in itertools.count(1):
        x += step
        yield x
```

Now `triangle_stream` only accumulates values from `itertools.count(1)`, well time to make use of [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
def triangle_stream():
    """ Infinite stream of triangle numbers. """
    return itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1))
```

or, to make it more obvious that you get a generator by calling `triangle_stream`:

```
def triangle_stream():
    """ Infinite stream of triangle numbers. """
    yield from itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1))
```

Comment: To further simplify: `triangle_stream = itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1))`

Comment: @200_success Correct me if I’m wrong, but this way you wouldn't be able to iterate several times over it, right?

Answer (score 3):

> Which of these two `nth_term` functions is more efficient?

There are two types of efficacy, memory and speed.
In terms of memory, they're about equal.
In terms of speed, the one that doesn't use `next` is better.
To test this you can use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('fn(gen, a)', 'from __main__ import nth_term_for as fn, triangle_stream as gen; a = 100', number=100000)
3.7175619061597445
>>> timeit('fn(gen, a)', 'from __main__ import nth_term_next as fn, triangle_stream as gen; a = 100', number=100000)
3.855789591803557
```

However, `if i == n - 1:` will reduce the speed of `nth_term_for`,
and so if you change the code to remove that minus from the loop you can improve the performance.
Take:

```
def nth_term_for_one(generator, n):
    """ Returns the nth term of an infinite generator. """
    for i, x in enumerate(generator(), 1):
        if i == n:
            return x
```

Finally, I wouldn't use any of the above functions.
Instead I'd use the [itertools recipe `nth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).
Where I named it `nth_term_iter` for a comparison.

There's a problem with `timeit`, where it can range quite drastically even on the same input.
And so I wrote a small program before to output graphs, that show the average, and the interquartile range of functions.
This showed that the best is hands down `itertools.islice`.
Here is the output that it generated:

[image]

Comment: Is the graphing program open source? If so could you post a link to it? It looks like a useful script to have around.

Comment: @Caridorc No, ): I'll put it on GitHub later, and will ping you a link

Comment: @Caridorc Yo, I've put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Peilonrayz/graphtimer) and made [a question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146434/42401). MIT or CC-BY-SA.

Comment: I have taken a look at it, it looks very feature rich. I have also written a similar graphing program https://github.com/CAridorc/Plot-Benchmark but it is much more basic :)